# Using the method of moments or GMM to estimate the parameters of a specific problem

Tags: autoregressive, method-of-moments, generalized-moments, compound-distributions

Given $(X_t)_{t \in \mathbb{Z}}$ an AR(1) process:
$$X_t = c+ \phi X_{t-1} + \epsilon_t, \quad \epsilon_t\sim WN(0,\sigma^2)$$
We can show that $E(X_t) = \frac{c}{1- \phi}$ and $E(X_t^2) = \frac{\sigma^2}{1- \phi^2} + (\frac{c}{1- \phi})^2$

Consider $\{(X_{t;j})_{t \in \mathbb{Z} }\}_{j \in \mathbb{N} }$ copies of $(X_t)_{t \in \mathbb{Z}}$, i.e., $X_{t;j} = c+ \phi X_{t-1;j} + \epsilon_{t;j}, \quad \epsilon_{t;j}\sim WN(0,\sigma^2), \,\,\, \forall j \in \mathbb{N}$.

Now, consider the $N \sim Po(\lambda)$ and the sum poisson:
$$Y_t = \sum_{j=1}^N X_{t;j}$$
(Note that $N$ is the same for all $t$)

According to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_Poisson_distribution), we have that $E(Y_t) = \lambda E(X_t)$ and $E(Y_t^2) = (\lambda E(X_t))^2 + \lambda E(X_t^2)$

In principle, the unknown parameters are: $\theta = (c,\sigma^2, \phi , \lambda )$.

There are several ways to estimate $\theta$ and one of them is using the method of moments or GMM. I can try to calculate the third and fourth moments, but for now, I'll just restrict myself to the first and second moments. For this, I will assume that $c$ and $\sigma$ are known. So $\theta = (\lambda, \phi)$.

My first attempt, using the method of moments, was

$$\frac{1}{T}\sum_{t=1}^T Y_t = E(Y_t) = \lambda \frac{c}{1- \phi}$$
$$\frac{1}{T}\sum_{t=1}^T Y_t^2 = E(Y_t^2) = \lambda^2\Big(\frac{\ c}{1- \phi}\Big)^2 + \lambda\Big( \frac{\sigma^2}{1- \phi^2} + (\frac{c}{1- \phi})^2 \Big)$$
Denote $\bar{Y}_T:= \frac{1}{T}\sum_{t=1}^T Y_t $, the first equation gives $\frac{c}{1- \phi} = \frac{\bar{Y}_T}{\lambda}$. Substituting this into the second equation, we have:
$$\frac{1}{T}\sum_{t=1}^T Y_t^2 = \bar{Y}_T^2 + \lambda \frac{\sigma^2}{1- \phi^2} + \frac{\bar{Y}_T^2 }{\lambda} $$

Here we have only one equation and we continue with two variables. So, I don't have a single solution. So I would like to know:

- Still using the method of moments, what would be the procedure in the case of an equation and two variables?
- Can I use GMM? For this, I need to find the moment conditions $E(g(Y_t, \theta)) = 0$ if and only if $\theta = \theta^*$. How can I find the $g$ function? Some light regarding this item can help me to know techniques for other cases
- What would be the appropriate procedure to be able to estimate, for example, $\theta = (c, \lambda, \phi)$?